# Soy principiante, que puedo mejorar en mi estructura?

Tags: java, excepciones, revisión-de-código, diseño-de-clases, ingenieria-del-software

Estoy empezando en Java y la verdad no tengo ningún problema con este código, pero quisiera escuchar sus recomendaciones frente a este que trata simplemente de suma o resta de números, de como puedo mejorarlo en temas de diseño y estandar.

primera clase la clase Main

```
package Pack1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
        Funciones.nombre();
        Excepciones.select();
        Excepciones.StringonInt();
        switch (Var.user_select) {
            case 's' -> Funciones.suma();
            case 'r' -> Funciones.resta();
        }
        System.out.println("El resultado es " + Var.oper_resul);
    }
}
```

clase Var que tiene las variables que utilizo en la app

```
package Pack1;

public class Var {
    public static char user_select;
    public static String user_nom = "";
    public static int n;
    public static int oper_resul;
    public static int cant;
}
```

clase Funciones en la que tengo la captura de los datos

```
package Pack1;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static Pack1.Var.n;

public class Funciones {
    static Scanner Fun = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void nombre(){
        while (Var.user_nom.length() == 0){
        System.out.println("Hola, ingrese por favor su nombre");
        Var.user_nom = Fun.nextLine();
        if (Var.user_nom.length() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No ingreso nombre");
        }
        }
    }
    public static void suma(){
        for (int i = 0; i < Var.cant; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese numero");
            n = Fun.nextInt();
            Var.oper_resul = Var.oper_resul + n;
        }
    }
    public static void resta(){
        for (int i = 0; i < Var.cant; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese numero");
            n = Fun.nextInt();
            Var.oper_resul = Var.oper_resul - n;
        }
    }
}
```

por ultimo la clase Excepciones que evita cualquier tipo de error que com

```
package Pack1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Excepciones {
    static Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
    public static void select (){
        try {
            while (Var.user_select != 'r' && Var.user_select != 's') {
                System.out.println("Hola " + Var.user_nom + " por favor dinos que operacion quieres realizar \nSumar: s\nRestar: r");
                Var.user_select = x.nextLine().charAt(0);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception NullSelect){
            System.out.println("No ingreso valor");
            Excepciones.select();
        }
    }
    public static void StringonInt (){
        try {
            System.out.println("Por favor dinos la cantidad de digitos a sumar");
            Var.cant = Integer.parseInt(x.nextLine());
        }
        catch (Exception StringOnInts){
            System.out.println("Ingrese un numero");
            Var.cant = 0;
            Excepciones.StringonInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He limpiado la pregunta un poco, quitando el texto que añadiste para pasar la validación. En cualquier caso te recomiendo completar el [tour] de bienvenida y leerte [ask] para ganar tu primera medalla en el sitio y conocer un poco más la *filosofía* de la comunidad

Comment: Agradezco mucho su colaboracion, tendre en cuenta esos detalles de los que me especifican, de hecho ya los implementé en mi codigo. Reforzare investigando la metodologia y la implementacion de los getters y los setters. Dejare la pregunta abierta por si mas personas contribuyen a mi duda. Nuevamente agradezco su colaboracion y su amabilidad.

Comment: Una vez que marcas una respuesta como aceptada se da la pregunta por "cerrada", pero realmente no significa nada especial: la gente podrá seguir respondiendo si así lo considera y tú, como OP (*original poster*) podrás cambiar la respuesta aceptada cuando quieras y todos podrán seguir votando. La principal diferencia es que en las búsquedas la pregunta aparecerá como "respondida"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empezaré por las convenciones Java: como comentas, no es un problema de que el código no vaya a compilar, pero si va a ser revisado por alguien más es bueno seguir *manual de estilo* de Java para evitar dudas y confusiones:

- Los nombres de los paquetes deben ser en minúsculas: los correcto sería declarar nombre como `pack1`.
- Los nombres de los métodos/funciones, de las variables locales, de los atributos... en general todos los nombres menos los de las constantes, se deben escribir siguiendo la notación *CamelCase*: no uses guiones bajos para separar las palabras, únelas empezando cada siguiente palabra con mayúscula. La primera palabra será mayúscula si es el nombre de una clase/interfaz: en lugar de `user_select`, podrías haber usando `userSelect`, por ejemplo.
- Esto no es sólo válido para Java, sino para cualquier lenguaje: usa nombres descriptivos para las variables y acciones para las funciones o métodos: la llamada a `Funciones.nombre();` me deja con dudas: ¿está obteniendo un nombre? ¿Está escribiéndolo en un fichero? Te recomiendo añadir **siempre** un verbo y acompañarlo de lo que haga falta para que quede muy claro qué hace la función. En los desarrollos en el Mundo Real<sup>TM</sup> se usan nombres como `pedirNombrePorTeclado()`. Es decriptivo y me ahorra tener que ir a la implementación para saber qué está haciendo. Lo ideal al leer un método es que no necesitemos meternos, como en la madriguera de un conejo, hasta el fondo para entenderlo. Una lectura del método debería ser suficiente para saber qué hace (aunque no exactamente cómo).

Sobre el código en sí, me sobra la clase `Var` y renombraría la clase `Excepciones`: puedes declarar variables locales en el método `main` y hacer que las funciones que llamas devuelvan los valores, uniendo toda la funcionalidad de leer por teclado en una única clase `EntradaTeclado`. El código podría ser algo como:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        // esta línea sobra
        // Scanner x = new Scanner (System.in);
        var nombre = EntradaTeclado.obtenerNombre();
        // pasamos como parámetro el nombre para poder saludar
        var seleccion = EntradaTeclado.seleccionaOperacion(nombre);
        var primerNumero = EntradaTeclado.obtenerEntero();
        var segundoNumero = EntradaTeclado.obtenerEntero();
        //guardamos lo que devuelva la llamada elegida
        var resultado = switch (seleccion) {
            case 's' -> Funciones.suma(primerNumero, segundoNumero);
            case 'r' -> Funciones.resta(primerNumero, segundoNumero);
        }
        System.out.println("El resultado es " + resultado);
    }
}
```

Nota: el código lo he escrito sin probarlo, puede contener erratas

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a es.SO (y gracias a Pablo por el formateo). Lo primero de todo, deberías de saber que toda clase Java debe tener mínimo, un constructor (vacío o no, eso es en función del uso) y getters y setters para cada propiedad privada del método. En tu caso, veo que la propiedad `user_select` la estás obteniendo a partir de `Var.`, cuando lo correcto es `Var.getUser_select`, y lo mismo ocurre cuando le quieres cambiar el valor a tu propiedad, deberías de haber `Var.setUser_select(text)`.

Lo segundo, la propiedad `Var` nunca es instanciada, por lo que, en realidad no existe ninguna forma de que puedas leer o escribir datos sobre las propiedades de la clase. Deberías crear una instancia del método para poder trabajar con ella. `Var var = new Var(...)`. Dejo los ... porque puedes crear la instancia con o sin parámetros.

Quitando estas dos cosas, tu código no parece mal formado, pero sí deberías, esto te lo digo como consejo, plantear primero a mano el flujo de datos que debería seguir tu proyecto. No es necesario que escribas código, pero sí el orden, las posibles salidas de datos y cómo tratarlas (un diagrama de flujo, para ser más correcto); de esta forma podrás plantear tu código de forma más limpia y organizada.

Comment: Está usando método estáticos y por eso no crea instancias. No es lo más elegante pero funciona

Comment: Sí, pero por eso le comenté lo de correcto, no que no fuera a compilar por eso.

Comment: Evidentemente, preferi hacerlos estaticos que instanciar los objetos. Pondre en practica el uso de instancias